# Length of ListView relative to the size of window(Visual Studio extension)

Tags: wpf, listview, visual-studio-extensions

I have developed one Visual Studio extension. The problem that I am encountering is the ListView as marked in the snapshot should not go below a certain point. The result here is correct:[image]. The ListView uses as much space as required to display 10 items. But when I shrink the window(Visual Studio extension) as shown here:[image], the `Next` button is over the ListView & `Previous` button is under the ListView. The expected result should be that in the second snapshot, the ListView should not go below 10 pixel above the `Next` & `Previous` buttons (as marked by green line). It already has scroll bar. How to solve this problem? Kindly ask for more information if needed.

**Update :** Here is the XAML as asked in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31542651/length-of-listview-relative-to-the-size-of-windowextension-in-wpf#comment51045547_31542651):

```
<UserControl x:Class="A.B.C"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:A.B.SE.Manager"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             DataContextChanged="UserControl_DataContextChanged" >
    <Grid>
        <ListView Margin="10,195,10,10" Name="questionListView" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SEQuestions}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Expander Cursor="Hand">
                            <Expander.Header>
                                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16" Foreground="#FF81B9F1">
                                    <Run Text="{Binding Path=title}"/>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Expander.Header>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=body_markdown}" Foreground="#FFB2AAAA" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                <WrapPanel>
                                    <Expander>
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <TextBlock>
                                            <Run Text="{Binding Path=comment_count, StringFormat='\{0} comment'}"/>
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <ListView Name="commentListView" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=comments}">
                                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <StackPanel>
                                                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=body_markdown}"/>
                                                        <Separator/>
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        </ListView>
                                    </Expander>
                                    <Expander>
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <TextBlock>
                                            <Run Text="{Binding Path=answer_count, StringFormat='\{0} answer'}"/>
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <ListView Name="answerListView" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=answers}">
                                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <StackPanel>
                                                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=body_markdown}"/>
                                                        <Separator/>
                                                        <Expander>
                                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                                <TextBlock>
                                                                    <Run Text="{Binding Path=comment_count, StringFormat='\{0} comments'}"/>
                                                                </TextBlock>
                                                            </Expander.Header>
                                                            <ListView Name="commentsOnAnswerListView" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=comments}">
                                                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                                        <StackPanel>
                                                                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=body_markdown}"/>
                                                                            <Separator/>
                                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                                            </ListView>
                                                        </Expander>
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        </ListView>
                                    </Expander>
                                </WrapPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=last_activity_date, StringFormat='Last activity at {0}'}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Expander>
                        <Separator/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Button Content="Next" Margin="10,740,10,10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60" Click="nextButtonClick"/>
        <Button Content="Previous" Margin="200,740,10,10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="60" Click="previousButtonClick"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `ClipToBounds="True"` on the ListView? The problem doesn't seem to be height or size of the ListView, but that the item inside the ListView is not clipping and is overflowing outside the ListView boundaries.

Comment: Anyway, could you show us your XAML? If it is indeed a Height problem, then it must be because of bad layout.

Comment: @almulo I have update the answer as you asked for long ag. Can you look into it?